# WPF WindowsFormsHost airspace issue even MetroWindow as popup used

Tags: wpf, windows-hosting

There is known "airspace "issue related to WindowsFormsHost used in WPF.

I use AvalonDock with some panes, one of them hosts a WindowsForms control.

I also use MetroWindow as a popup for showing informations.

Unfortunately when popup is being shown and under it is AvalonDock.Pane with hosted window visible  then it is always on most top.

Do you have any suggestions how to solve this issue?

MetroWindow has some properties as MetroWindow.Topmost but it does not work as I expected.

Comment: *"Do you have any suggestions how to solve this issue?"* how about don't use components with known airspace issues. There's no real workaround, so maybe you can find an alternative WPF component?

Comment: you are right that the best solution will be to find or write it in WPF, I preferred to asked just in case someone find better way. Anyway, it seems there is no real workaround and it would be better to close it.